# Edit specific object in xml without additional changes in bash

Tags: xml, bash, editing, xmlstarlet

I need edit some value in my xml files. And I use this code:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u \
'//some_folder/buildElement[@name="element_name"]/@some_value' \
-v $var_to_change ${PATH}/my_file.xml
```

And it is working but not like I expected. I mean, my target value is edit correctly, but additional is changed others line f.e. is remove space or added `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

Input:
IS: edit element_name value and remove some space in another lines or add tag  on 1 line in xml.

Should be:
edit only element_name value

How can I edit only my expected value without any validation of xml or changes in not expected lines?

Comment: It's not clear which tool you are using. Is this an `xmlstarlet` command line? Please [edit] to provide a [mre] with an example XML file which exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: sorry, I my bad. Yes, I am using xmlstarlet

Comment: And the input file which illustrates this ...?

Comment: So your actual question amounts to "how can I get `xmlstarlet` to not normalize spacing etc on lines it is not otherwise changing?"

Comment: More or less :D I'd like to edit only `[@name="element_name"]/@some_value'`

Comment: For not adding the declaration (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`), use `--omit-decl`,  see:  `xmlstartlet ed --help`      (And, please, add the XML to this question if you want/need answer on the other part of this question.)